# How to Access Map Object in Angular Template

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, typescript, angular2-template

I have a custom class in Angular4 to manage a map (angular component as well). My class has a template inside which i have ngui-map element (imported from the library below). I have been able to bind to events triggered by this element (such as map move, map click etc.).

The questions is: is it possible to access this map object from my typescript code? I need to access the map's properties inside some button click, but I just cant figure out how.

The only solution I have been able to come up with is to hook up event handler for the map move and keep storing the current map location (which are sent as event args) inside some helper variables and then use those variables, but surely there is another better way?

I am new to angular so sorry if this question is a bit basic or doesnt make any sense. I ve tried googling but I cant seem to word the query correctly to get relevant results.

ngui-map
https://github.com/ng2-ui/map

Comment: Where do you want to access it from? From a different component or some service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a component that implements this map, you can use a `template variable` to call the methods of the component in the template.

For example:

```
<map-component #map></map-component>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="onClick(map.getCoordinates())></button>
```

This is assuming your MapComponent has public methods that allow you to get the information you need.